# Modern Authentication Exchange Online with C#

Tags: c#, authentication, office365, exchange-server

With the upcoming update with the Microsoft Online policy (Baseline) we're not allowed to use legacy authentication, as far as I am concerned this includes SMTP. Assuming we are not able to disable it, how will we be sending e-mail after October 2020 using C#, or other languages?

Modern authentication seems to become the one and only - preferred - way of sending e-mail.

In extend, how should one send email as/on behalf of a share mailbox with baseline enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the deprecation of basic authentication last October some stuff has changed. Basic Authentication for SMTP is still available but, as mentioned above, will eventually be deprecated as well.

I now use Microsoft Graph for a lot of things including sending email.

Please see [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) for more information on sending email using Microsoft Graph.